# Jmeter - read parameters from csv and write back updated parameters

Tags: api, csv, jmeter

I'm using Jmeter for testing. I need to use some keys in order to perform login, and then change the keys.
I understood that the best way to do it is to create csv file that contains two variables.
I understand how I can read the parameters (using 'CSV Data Set Config'), but I still don't know how to extract specific parameters from result (new keys) and save them in file instead the old ones.

Comment: I don't understand, you have two values (used to login in) and after the test, you want to overwrite them by new values ? So you want to update you .csv file ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Regular Expression Extractor` to extract the values from the response. This [site](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65150-using-regex-regular-expression-extractor-with-jm) will give you an idea how it works.

It is NOT a good idea to write in the same file which is read by CSV dataset config. Instead, you can use `Beanshell post processor` to create a CSV file & write as you want.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer;


f = new FileOutputStream("/your/file/path/filename.csv", true); 
p = new PrintStream(f); 
p.println("content,to be,written,in,csv,file");
p.close();
f.close();
```

Comment: thanks for answering. the thing is that I'm using oauth 2.0 APIs for access token and refresh token. I need to use the refresh token to get a new access token and then update the file with the new access token and refresh token. so it's only 2 variables that update every time. can I use this script also to update a csv file in specific places?